# Codeception REST timeout issue

Tags: curl, codeception

I'm trying to increase the Codeception REST timeout, but it doesn't seem to be working.

That's what I have

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api:
        - REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            timeout: 90
```

Timeout error I'm getting

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem too. This was my Fix

in acceptance.suite.yml

```
    # Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# suite for acceptance tests.
# perform tests in browser using the WebDriver or PhpBrowser.
# If you need both WebDriver and PHPBrowser tests - create a separate suite.

class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - REST
    config:
        REST:
            timeout: 90 # or 90000 the same result
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://YOUR_URL_TO_YOUR_PUBLIC_FOLDER/public'
            curl:
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 300 // in Seconds
```

My problem was that i put only the REST in it with "depends" to PhpBrowser but you need to configure the PhpBrowser to setup the Timeout.

I hope i could help and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Thomas, I've added this to my api.suite.yml file and it worked.

`class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Helper\Api
        - REST
        - PhpBrowser
    config:
        REST:
            depends: PhpBrowser
            timeout: 90
        PhpBrowser:
            url: ''
            curl:
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 90`

Comment: Delete that `timeout: 90` parameter, it doesn't do anything. The only parameter used by REST module is `url` .

Answer (score 0):

For Codeception 4.

Add to api.suite.yml or acceptance.suite.yml something like this

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - PhpBrowser:
        url: https://localhost/index-test.php
        timeout: 5
#        curl:
#          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: true // add some curl option
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        url: https://localhost/index-test.php
        part: Json
    - Yii2:
        configFile: 'tests/config/test.php'
        part: [orm, fixtures]
```