# How do I fix cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 90001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Tags: php, api, curl, laravel-5

I am running API tests using codeception, and I am getting this error

`"[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException] cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 90001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received"`

I have looked through the internet and found this [Codeception REST timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43181920/codeception-rest-timeout-issue) article I followed everything but I still get the same error. Please look at my api.suite.yml below

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - \Helper\Api
    - REST
    - Laravel5
    - Asserts
    - Db
  config:
    REST:
      depends: PhpBrowser
    PhpBrowser:
      url: 'http://localhost:8001'
      curl:
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT: 90
```

Comment: You are making a connection with curl. Are you sure the resource is available? Maybe you can/may share your resource so we can check/test it. Also some code examples help greatly in getting attention: Why would anyone bother answering an incomplete question ? ;)